# Mojave: Update installed but still indicated as not finished

Tags: mojave, software-update, auto-update

The "software update" in the preferences says that my system is up-to-date "macOS Mojave 10.14.6", but in the Apple menu bar in the upper left it is still saying **"1 update available"**.

I wouldn't bother, but the problem is that unless the installation is - somehow - marked as completely finished or redone, I can **only boot in safe mode**, as in regular mode an app of my company is showing up and asks me to complete the installation. **I cannot skip or cancel this app.**

**Yes, this is in fact a case for my company's Mac support, but** their solution is to **bring in the laptop and re-install** the whole system. Besides the fuss setting up the machine afterwards this requires me a **130km drive one-way.**

That's why I'm trying to find a solution myself. I have admin permission for the next 22 hours, so any hint in the near future would be great.

Comment: What's the result of `sudo softwareupdate -l` (entered in Terminal)? The command lists all available updates.

Comment: It says "No new software available"

Comment: I tried `defaults write com.apple.systempreferences AttentionPrefBundleIDs 0`, which made the notification go away, but the app of my company still thinks the installation has not finished...

Comment: Do you remember the name of the last software update? I assume it was Security Update 2020-002 for Mojave. Download the dmg manually: [Download Security Update 2020-002 (Mojave)](https://updates.cdn-apple.com/2020/macos/061-90746-20200319-43428f02-227d-4756-83dc-286bdae19732/SecUpd2020-002Mojave.dmg) and install it again by opening the dmg and the pkg inside the dmg.